# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Batch file error on csv filtering

Tags: csv, batch-file

I was trying to write what I thought was a pretty simple batch file that took an existing output as csv and using the comma as a delimiter, it would then write me a csv with the data I needed in the format I needed. This all worked well except that as the file is processed the terminal outputs "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." So i get about 500ish lines correctly written out of close to 800.

```
@echo off
title Clean email list for Canvas

call :sub >canvasUser.csv

:sub
echo user_id,integration_id,login_id,password,authentication_provider_id,first_name,last_name,full_name,sortable_name,short_name,email,status >> canvasUser.csv
for /F "tokens=1-10 skip=1 delims=," %%a in (Student_Export_2018MilleniumRAW.csv) do (
echo %%a, ,%%j, ,microsoft,%%d,%%c,%%d %%c,"%%c, %%d",%%d %%c,%%j,active >> canvasUser.csv)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes, I hope it helps.

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Clean email list for Canvas

Call :sub "canvasUser.csv"
Exit /B

:sub
(    Echo user_id,integration_id,login_id,password,authentication_provider_id,first_name,last_name,full_name,sortable_name,short_name,email,status
     For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Tokens=1-10 Delims=," %%a In ("Student_Export_2018MilleniumRAW.csv") Do (
         Echo %%a, ,%%j, ,microsoft,%%d,%%c,%%d %%c,"%%c, %%d",%%d %%c,%%j,active))>"%~1"
```

Comment: This works perfectly!! thanks so much! Can I impose on you to explain where I was going wrong or what you did to make it read the whole file rather than just the first 512 records?